# ModelNotFoundError: No module named 'guardian.shortcuts'

Tags: django, python-3.8, django-guardian, guardian

I am trying to run a Django project, I tried to import `assign_perm` and `remove_perm` from `guardian.shortcuts` (code listed here: `from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm, remove_perm`).

and got an error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'guardian.shortcuts'`

I am using python3.8.9 and django2.0.7. I have already successfully tried install guardian(0.2.2) and Django-guardian(2.4.0), and I can import guardian successfully directly. Please help me to figure it out. THX!

P.S. I tried to `print(guardian.__file__)` and the output is here:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/guardian/__init__.py
```

Comment: _I have already tried install guardian_ What do you mean you "tried"?  Did you successfully install it or not?

Comment: sry for the unclear message, I have already successfully installed guardian and Django-guardian, and they are all  in my python Environment.

Comment: Do you have a local file of your own named `guardian.py`?

Comment: Show us the output of this code `import guardian; print(guardian.__file__)`

Comment: I don't have the a file named guardian.py, and I uploaded the "print(guardian.__file__)" output in my answer part. Please have a check

Answer (score 0):

emmmm actually I don't know why, I just use `pip3` to uninstall `guardian` and `Django-guardian`, and reinstall `Django-guardian` and it worked. and I found that both `assign_perm` and `assign` is available for `Django-guardian2.4.0`, but only `remove_perm` (rather than `remove`) is available for this version. If you struggled with this issue and following solutions above still cannot help you can have a try for my solution. Hope this can help you.